# I can't perform login test in JMeter

Tags: testing, jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing

I am trying to test login portion in JMeter but so far no luck. I tried to record the login in blazemeter. But it only hit the IP, so I have added 2 more http request and manually added the credentials. JMeter is not forwarding any cookies. How Can I solve this issue?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i7a3h.png)

Answer (score 0):

- If you're sure that the browser is sending a [HTTP request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods) and BlazeMeter Chrome Extension doesn't catch it - report the issue by [opening a BlazeMeter Support Request ticket](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207491229-How-to-Open-a-Support-Ticket).
- Alternatively you can try recording using JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html) and see whether it is capable of capturing all the requests
- In any case whether you're recording the requests or building the test script manually don't forget to [correlate](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html#correlate-start) any dynamic parameters